# How to make all the reference variables None in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, nonetype

I got a typical ListNode class something like below,

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self,val, next = None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

I created two instances of this class, and assigned one of the object to a variable called next in first instance as below,

```
node = ListNode(1)
next_node = ListNode(2)
node.next = next_node
```

However, if I assign `nnode = None`, the `node.next` still points to the instance `next_node` and is not `None`.

```
print( next_node == node.next) # Prints True
next_node = None
print( node.next.val) # Prints 1
```

How can I make all the reference variables (e.g. `node.next` in above case) make None without explicitly assigning them to None?

Comment: I don't think you can. Why do you want to?

Comment: If by “reference variables” you mean “variables (attributes) I’m using as references within the lists”, you can’t. If you mean it in some language sense, well… the concept of a “reference variable” doesn’t exist.

Comment: `next_node` is simply a *name* that maps to a pointer. assigning `next_node=None` simply points `next_node` to the singleton, `None`.

Comment: You can't; that would violate the semantics of separate variables.  If you want that effect, you'll have to declare your own reference-handling class for such "follow me" variables.  Alternately, write a function with the semantics you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like your question. Probably this is not exactly what you are looking for, but I have found `weakref` library. With it you could try to modify your code:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val, next_=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next_ = next_

    def get_next(self):
        try:
            self.next_.check()
        except AttributeError: # if self.next_ exists then it does not have 'check' method.
            return self.next_
        except ReferenceError: # if it does not exists it will raise this exception
            return None
```

Then instead of assigning `node.next_ = next_node`, you can create weakref:

```
node = ListNode(1)
next_node = ListNode(2)
node.next_ = weakref.proxy(next_node)

print( next_node == node.next_) # prints True
next_node = None
print(node.get_next()) # prints None
```

Hope this will help solve your problem!

Edit:
I have also changed the name `next` to `next_` because `next` is a builtin function

Comment: This isn’t a reliable solution – other things could keep that reference alive, and it’s not guaranteed to die at the right time either.